# Применение Query к массиву

Tags: google-apps-script

Можно ли функцией делать запросы к массиву? Получаю ошибку undefined.
var Journal =[]
var JournalFin = Query(Journal, "Select * WHERE (Journal[1] == '2586')")

Comment: Судя из того что у вас то `var Journal =[]` - это пустой массив потому и `Journal[1]` возвращает вам undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Этот вопрос не имеет однозначного и ожидаемого ответа. Вам необходимо рассмотреть несколько альтернативных подходов.

### 1. Чистый JS

Подход применяет возможности языка GS, который является прямым потомком JS. Методы массивов `filter()` или `reduce()` отлично подходят:

```
function pureJS(data, journalIndex) {
  var journal = data;
  var journalFin = journal.filter(function(row){
    return row[4] === this.val;
  }, {val: journalIndex});
  return journalFin;
}
```

### 2. AlaSQL

Библиотека, которая позволяет применять SQL-запросы непосредственно к данным JS. Для установки требуется подключение библиотеки или собственное портирование https://github.com/oshliaer/alasqlgs

```
function alaSQL(data, journalIndex) {
  var alasql = AlaSQLGS.load();
  alasql.options.modifier = 'MATRIX';
  var journal = data;
  var journalFin = alasql("SELECT * FROM ? AS data WHERE data.[4]=?", 
                          [journal, journalIndex]);
  return journalFin;
}
```

### 3. "Передергивание" формул

Неоднозначное название подхода означает то, что можно подумать. Такой способ иногда используют, но только в отсутствие альтернатив. Принцип простой: создаем формулу, ждем ее пересчета, забираем результаты ее расчетов.

```
function formulaTweak(spreadsheet, rangeAddr, journalIndex) {
  var sheet = getSheetByName(spreadsheet, "yabadabaduuu_rnd");
  sheet.clear()
  .getRange("A1")
  .setFormula(Utilities.formatString('=QUERY(%s; "SELECT * WHERE E=%s")',
                                     rangeAddr, journalIndex));
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  var journalFin = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  journalFin.shift();
  return journalFin;  
}
```

Данные и полный листинг прораммы-примера можно увидеть [тут](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0Bztea6vSatozYmZTVjlFRmhtRFU?usp=sharing)

Comment: Спасибо! Т.е. получается "влоб" применить query  к массиву в GS нельзя, это функция воркшита? нужно использовать альтернативные методы, которые вы перечислии?

Comment: В некоторых приложениях существуют интерпретаторы, но не в случае с Гугл.